# xcode Scrolling text with animation

Tags: xcode, animation, scroll, label

How to do so: the screen is static line when I scroll the text, and some of it goes over the line, that part changes color

Comment: Question is very unclear

Comment: can u provide any example link or image?

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_4064547_6834645.png
text above the purple line to be purple when scrolling